# Unable to install scikit-learn using python 3.11.0

Tags: scikit-learn

```
I am using below setup
poetry: 1.2.2
pyenv: 2.3.5-3-g0726e02e
python: 3.11.0
scikit-learn: 1.1.2

I am trying to install scikit-learn using command:
**poetry add scikit-learn **

But I am getting error as below:

 Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [273 lines of output]
      Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
      setup.py:128: DeprecationWarning:
      
        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
      ....
      ....
      ....
    self.finalize_unix()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-go8f9tm1/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/install.py", line 498, in finalize_unix
          self.select_scheme("posix_prefix")
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-go8f9tm1/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/install.py", line 528, in select_scheme
          return self._select_scheme(resolved)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-go8f9tm1/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/install.py", line 537, in _select_scheme
          setattr(self, attrname, scheme[key])
                                  ~~~~~~^^^^^
      KeyError: 'headers'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

what I am missing?
```

As in error message suggests to try with setuptools < 60.0.0
I tried **poetry run pip install setuptools==59.8.0**

while doing **poetry add scikit-learn**, it auto upgrades **setuptools to version 65.0** something and fails with error.

Although, using above setup(excluding scikit-learn) I am able to successfully install numpy, pandas, scipy etc without any need to downgrade the setuptools version.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Only related issue I found is this: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/24446 which seems to be closed and merged to main?

However I tried installing from github directly via `pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git` and it didn't work either.

Comment: Hi Ludecan, I also tried this command --> poetry run pip install scikit-learn, this also failed.

Comment: There was some more activity in the Github issue. It seems the wheels are pushed now and scikit-learn installs. I'm stuck on statsmodels now :sweat_smile:. Got to wait a few more days.

Comment: Hi Ludecan, Now it is working(scikit-learn). Yes we need to wait for rest to get fixed.

Answer (score 5):

I got it via: `pip3 install -U scikit-learn`

Comment: Please don't repeat answers

Comment: This is actually a unique answer (uses pip3 not pip) and references the change in package name "scimitar-learn" which pip3 flags in a response "The 'sklearn' PyPI package is deprecated, use 'scikit-learn' rather than 'sklearn' for pip commands."  So this should actually be the right answer

Answer (score 1):

This should install scikit-learn:

pip install -U sklearn

It worked on my system with Python 3.11.

Comment: Thanks starter, Yes it is working now after the issue is been fixed.

Comment: I found this video, which let me install CUDA, Tensorflow, etc.
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEFKlRSd8Ic